# jquery: can callback function know to which node it is attached to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I attach callback functions to data attributes of each query result object (serveral ones!) like so:

```
$(".myclass").data('callback', (node, value) => {
    console.log("Callback called on node with id: " + node.attr('id'));
    // do something with value
});


// When called, the actual node the callback is attached to needs to be passed as well:

let callback = node.data('callback');
callback(node, 123);
```

Is it possible that the function, once called, can know to which node it belongs? Kind of a closure that stores a reference to each query object. `this` or `$(this)` don't work, obviously.

Kind of:

```
$(".myclass").data('callback', (value) => {
    let node = respective query result object;
    console.log("Callback called on node with id: " + node.attr('id'));
    // do something with value
});

...

let callback = node.data('callback');
callback(123);
```

Maybe something similar as jquery's `on()` or `bind()`, but these are restricted to events, not custom functions that can be called from outside.

Answer (score 3):

Two options for you:

1. Use the event system
2. Write a plugin

### Use the Event System

Approach this through the event system rather than by storing functions via `data`:

1. Attach a handler for your own custom event

   1. Use a traditional function so jQuery can set `this` to the element when calling it
   2. Accept two parameters: The event, and the extra value you want to pass
2. "Call" the callback via [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Example:

```js
// Notice we're using a traditional function, not an arrow function
$(".myclass").on("callback-event", function (event, value) {
    // In the function, `this` refers to the DOM element the event
    // was triggered on. (Note it's not a jQuery wrapper.)
    console.log(
        `Callback called on node with id: ${this.id} with value ${value}`
    );
});

const elements = $(".myclass");
const node = $(elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length)]);

// Calling the callback
node.trigger("callback-event", 123);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="myclass">one</div>
<div id="two" class="myclass">two</div>
<div id="three" class="myclass">three</div>
```

This also gives you the option of having multiple "callbacks" (which is to say, event handlers) attached to the event.

### Write a Plugin

You could write a plugin in order to attach your own functions to jQuery objects. The function wouldn't only exist on specific jQuery objects, but you can make it act like it does.

```js
// Basic plugin template with your function in it
(($) => {
    // This needs to be a traditional function, not an arrow function,
    // so `this` can be set by how it's called
    $.fn.callback = function(value) {
        // Here, `this` is the jQuery object which may have multiple
        // elements (or none) in it
        // You can filter out elements that don't have your class
        // on them if you like; otherwise, just remove the `filter`
        // call here and use `this.each(...)`.
        this.filter(".myclass").each((_, element) => {
            // Here, `element` is a DOM element
            console.log(
                `Callback called on node with id: ${element.id} with value ${value}`
            );
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

const elements = $(".myclass");
const node = $(elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length)]);

// Calling the callback
node.callback(123);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="myclass">one</div>
<div id="two" class="myclass">two</div>
<div id="three" class="myclass">three</div>
```

Comment: Thumbs up for this quick and clever answer! I like the clean approach, thank you!